# Можно ли при загрузке картинки сделать несколько модификаций картинки, используя только stream

Tags: node.js, multer

Имею nodejs приложение.

Можно ли во время загрузки картинки, пропускать её через imageMin, вычислять md5 и сохранять.

Можно ли выполнить все эти операции в одном потоке?

Comment: [можно!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1228005/2659) ловишь stream, делаешь из него буфер, запускаешь минимизатор, вычисляешь сумму, пишешь на диск. сделаешь или написать ответ?

Comment: С буфером раньше работал, тут такой вопрос... Обязательно ли весь поток собирать в буфер? Я от этого уйти хотел, в силу ограниченого количества оперативной памяти. Да и файлы могут быть разные, - pdf, к примеру. Не смогу же я 100+ мегабайт загрузить в буффер, что бы "оптимизировать". Желательно, чтобы буффер был статический, в 2 мб, а все оптимизации шли в момент загрузки.

Comment: хороший вопрос. я просматривал краем глаза доку к imagemin и не нашел там возможности сунуть стрим. я мало знаю про алгоритмы оптимизации картинок, так что, возможно, стоит просто поискать подходящий минификатор, работающий с потоком, но мне кажется там всё равно прочитают в буфер - как работать с картинкой не получив её всю?.. короче, тут надо искать и смотреть исходники библиотек

Comment: посмотри, вроде бы https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/performance#results умеет потоки. однако там нужно будет как-то вручную сконфигурировать эту оптимизацию

Comment: @nörbörnën, https://prnt.sc/wsx6cv Хоть и в вображении не укладывается - как можно оптимизировать фотку через "поток".

Comment: чудес не бывает, почитай [исходники](https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin-pngquant/blob/master/index.js), - он берёт буфер или stream и пускает на вход консольной утилите (ок, тут пока вроде экономим) и после этого выдаёт назад то, что консольная утилита выбрасывает в stdout и `Returns Promise<Buffer>`. простыми словами: память, которую ты хочешь сэкономить, на время обработки съест консольная утилита, но в результате твоё приложение получит Buffer меньшего размера

Comment: Сейчас кручу твой исходник для накладывания "водных знаков". Потом, думаю использовать https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp