# Как обработать formData запрос

Tags: javascript, node.js

Делаю post-запрос на сервер, в теле запроса передаю FormData, в ней изображение.

Как можно обработать это изображение?

Вот моя попытка -

```js
router.post('/image',
    cors(corsOptions),
    async(req, res) => {
        try {
            const reqBody = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body));

            console.log(reqBody)

            return res.status(200).json({
                msg: "ok",
            });
        } catch (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                msg: "a"
            });
        }
    }
);
```

При попытке консолить тело запроса, выводится пустой объект.

На всякий случай сам запрос -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1228005 - всякие более сложные вещи, которые можно творить с multer

Comment: @nörbörnën, возможно ли сделать это без multer?

Comment: @Voprositel, в любом случае нужен парсер, который поймет formdata и распарсит его

Comment: а почему ты спрашиваешь? так-то сделать можно. можно выкинуть multer и написать вокруг https://github.com/mscdex/busboy - A node.js module for parsing incoming HTML form data, вокруг которого написан multer. можно выкинуть busboy, прочесть несколько раз https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7578 и написать свой загрузчик. можно поставить https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable, норм тема

Comment: @nörbörnën, в принципе вопрос отпал, я представлял multer не как парсер, а как утилита

Comment: multer - не парсер, а миддлваре для express, которая написана вокруг _парсера_ (busboy)